# cannot convert from ArrayList<Integer> to ArrayList<String>

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a ArrayList with integer value and I want to read this value from another ArrayList consist string value. How can I do that ?

```
    public static ArrayList<Integer> scorerValue = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

and I want read here using

```
ArrayList<String> score_Number ;
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? (Think: you'll need to convert each integer into a string...)

Comment: Please clarify. You want to take each `Integer` in one list and convert it to a `String` and put it in the other list?

Comment: Do you know how to iterate through an array?

Comment: Have you tried reading http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/ ? The new Java 8 has an elegant way of doing it using lambdas.

Answer (score 1):

Okay. So let's first declare our `List<String>`..

```
List<String> score_Number = new ArrayList<String>();

// Remember you program to an interface. Not a concrete implementation.
```

Then to convert you..

```
// Do some magic.
```

That's right Magic. Magic involving [the toString() method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29). You will need to call `toString()` in a [for each loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html). Finally, you will need to use the [List.add() method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add%28E%29), to add the newly created `String` values to your list `score_Number`.

***NOTE***: Follow the naming conventions. `score_Number` should be `scoreNumber`.

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
ArrayList<Integer> integerList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
// add Integer Elements
ArrayList<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>();
for(Integer i : integerList){
    stringList.add(i+"");
}
```

Comment: The idea is we don't directly answer questions that haven't shown reasonable attempts.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
       ArrayList<Integer> scorerValue = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        scorerValue.add(1);
        ArrayList<String> score_Number = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (Integer i : scorerValue)
            score_Number.add(i.toString());
        System.out.println(score_Number);
```